# Authenticating Using Ajax & Postman code, but variables not understood by server.

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication, postman

I am using code from the Postman app to build a simple AJAX authentication form on a  website. I'm not really familiar with Postman and this is what I did. I first set up all the form stuff (get button, get input fields, then run function on click):

```
var registerbtn = document.getElementById("register");

var regemail = document.getElementById("regemail").value;
var regfirst = document.getElementById("regfirst").value;
var reglast = document.getElementById("reglast").value;
var regpass1 = document.getElementById("regpass1").value;
var regpass2 = document.getElementById("regpass2").value;

registerbtn.addEventListener("click", newRegister);
```

Then I took the code from the postman app for a Jquery Ajax request. It looked as follows:

```
function newRegister() {
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "{{https://some url}}",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "Postman-Token": "{{some token}}"
    },
    "data": {
      "password": regpass1,
      "passwordConfirmation": regpass2,
      "firstName": regfirst,
      "email": regemail,
      "lastName": reglast
    }
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I hardcode the variables to some string (like instead of `regemail`, I put "email@email.com") the code works and is uploaded to the server, but using these variables it does not. I get a 400 (bad request) error. I don't have access to the server atm.

What mistake am I making with the input variables? I've tried to `JSON.stringify` the values but that didn't help.

I have already disabled CORS for the purposes of development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was variable scope; I should've put the variables inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add:

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

Comment: Didn't effect the error. Also I'm pretty sure I have the right contentType, unless you meant add it to another part of the code.